# Need help understanding edits to a post.

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently posted something and it ended up being edited. I couldn't really understand what was changed but suspect that it could help make me a better poster because nothing changed visually but it was labeled as markdown-ify and I'm sure there was something wrong with the basic structure of what I posted originally. Anyway I'd love to know what I can do to be the best member I can. Edits are at 
https://superuser.com/posts/170201/revisions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been changed from a manual list to a markdown list.

The first just becomes a set of `p`aragraph tags.
The latter is converted in to proper html `ol` (ordered list) element.

If you've not already seen it before, have a look at the [Markdown Edit Help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) page.